# Minecraft Bedrock Edition Item Models?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I have seen various Minecraft Bedrock edition maps with floating items.
Example (carrot above villager head):
[image: img]

How can I add this using command blocks or addons?

Comment: Does the villager still move? Kinda surprised that actually exists.

Comment: No, it doesnt. @MarkGiraffe

Comment: Have you checked out [blockbench](https://blockbench.net/) and the [vanilla behaviour and resource packs](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/addons)?